# How to visualise the distribution of method length in source code

Tags: data-visualization

I want to give a presentation about the status of a certain software project. Among the problems, there is a lot of long, spaghetti-like methods. I plan to parse the source code and gather stats about the method length (measured in lines of code).

My question is: what is the best way of visualizing the data I will gather? The point I want to make here is, that the methods are too long and therefore the code requires a large refactor to improve the quality.

Comment: What data will you gather besides method length? How is method length measured?

Comment: The method length would be measured in lines of code. I didn’t plan to gather other data, but if there is something I could gather with an automatic script, I could do it.